# SQLite.SQLiteException thrown in Xamarin.Android when trying to create a table

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to create a simple local SQLite database using Xamarin.Android.
The code for that is:

```
string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
SQLiteConnectiondb = new SQLiteConnection (Path.Combine (folder, "Experimental.db"));
db.CreateTable<Employee>();
```

My Employee class is:

```
[Table("Employees")]
    public class Employee
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        int Id { get; set; }

        string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

The exception I am getting whenever the code reaches db.CreateTable is:

```
 SQLite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error
  at at SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare2 (intptr,string) <IL 0x0002c, 0x00160>
  at at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.Prepare () <IL 0x00011, 0x0008f>
  at at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery () <IL 0x00013, 0x000b3>
  at at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Execute (string,object[]) <IL 0x00041, 0x001ab>
  at at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateTable (System.Type,SQLite.CreateFlags) <IL 0x000a4, 0x005cb>
  at at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateTable<Core.Employee> (SQLite.CreateFlags) <0x00063>
```

To the inexperienced eyes of mine, this does look like an issue related to SQLite itself. Has anyone else faced this and if so - what was your work-around?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your ORM, but it seems to be generating invalid SQL. Make sure that it is configured correctly and that you're not using a buggy version.

Comment: I have downloaded it from the Components Store of Xamarin, so I'm assuming it should be stable. Posted on their forums as well, just in case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the properties on the Employee class public so SQLite can see them when it's creating the columns for your table:

```
[Table("Employees")]
public class Employee
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Ahh, a foolish mistake. Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: In case this doesn't solve the issue for anyone, it turns out all class parameters have to be `{ get; set; }` as well, not just public.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is Linker Options, some times the SQLite-net package was not link with your project. Have to check linker behaviour , in iOS link SDK assemblies only and **mtouch :** **--linkskip=SQLite-net** then its working.